# How to deal with nightmares?

Tags: stress, health

I had a really bad boss for the past 3 years and finally managed to get a new job where both my boss and co-workers are amazing. I've been working here for the past 3 months, yet every 2-3 nights I have nightmares where my old boss shows up at my new workplace. (He must be Freddie Kruger)

I've tried a few things that people have suggested, but nothing seems to work. So I'm looking for tips to help with this. Here's what I've done:

- Exercise 1 hour every other day
- 10 minutes of Yoga before and after sleep
- Play ukulele before Yoga - I was told ukulele is the instrument of peace
- Eat healthy
- Take a hot shower

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: This sounds a bit beyond the scope of this site... but if those tips didn't work, maybe it's time to talk to a therapist.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about personal health and not workplace-related issues. Suggest seeking professional medical advice. For Freddie Kruger-related questions, please consider turning to Movies.SE, for personal productivity problems - to [Personal Productivity SE](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: hmm.. sorry. I wasn't sure where work related stress questions went. It seemed borderline with personal health.. How do I tag this question to be moved as I don't have enough rep to move the question.

Comment: @ChewbaccaDefence: Normally you flag the question for moderator attention, but I don't think there is a personal health stack exchange site. I think you best bet is to start talking to your family doctor and see what they recommend.

Comment: Since you left the old job and the new one doesn't appear to be the problem, it's no longer a work-related problem, so your job isn't the solution. Are you suffering from any othere symptoms?

Comment: I started grinding my teeth at nights. I'm seeing a dentist tomorrow about that. Biggest change is that my new job is programming so I don't interact with people much (most of the team is off shore) and my old job was an instructor so I saw about 200+ people per day.

Comment: Maybe the nightmare isn't due to your old boss, it's due to other stress factors such as government snooping or what is now 'the global war on everything' (GWOE).  Hopefully you aren't being paid in Rupees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I'm not a doctor (nor do I play one on TV), but a dream like this strikes me as something needing closure.  Do you have any outstanding issues with the old boss?

Something you wouldn't want your new colleagues to know?

You could try writing a (never sent) letter to your old boss, once you start the underlying reason may appear on the page.